# Convert complex DB2 SQL with ROW_NUMBER() to mongo query

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, window-functions

I'm new to MongoDB, I'm trying to convert existing DB2 query to MongoDB. I'm Using Java to run this query.

Current DB2 Query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT MBI.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER Order by PDATE DESC AS rownumber 
  FROM USER1.COLLECTION1 MBI, USER1.COLLECTION2 IC  
  WHERE MBI.VISIBILITY = 1 and MBI.MBOXID = '1234' 
    AND UPPER(MBI.MBOXITID) >= '1234555' 
    AND UPPER(MBI.CATEGORY) = 'S' 
    AND UPPER(MBI.Mimetype) = 'PDF' 
    AND UPPER(MBI.Psystemid) = 'TBA' 
    AND days(current date) - days(MBI.PDATE) < 20 
    AND MBI.MBOXITID = IC.ICONTENTID) AS FinalResult 

    WHERE rownumber BETWEEN 1 and 2 Order by PDATE DESC
```

Am really not sure how to get the ROW_NUMBER details in MongoDB.

Can you help for me solve problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case: are you migrating data from DB2 to MongoDB or trying to query existing data in DB2 with the MongoDB protocol? If using MongoDB directly, can you include an example of your MongoDB documents, the query approach you've tried, and confirm your specific version of MongoDB? Your original query assumes a very relational approach (eg. subselects and joins) and does a lot of field manipulation to match results. If this is a common query (or you want it to be efficient), a recommendable starting point would be reconsidering your data model to better fit your use case

Comment: @Stennie Thank you Stennie for your reply!
Yes we are in the process of migration, so we are converting/updating existing JAVA API's. During the Java API updates am facing this challenge.
**Requirement:**   
**Collection #1:**
VISIBILITY, MBOXID, MBOXITID, CATEGORY, Mimetype, Psystemid

**Collection #2:**
ICONTENTID

Sub Query: Matching above filed with some values and dynamically creating a ROWNUMBER based PDATE field (_i.e., Order by PDATE DESC AS rownumber_).
Main Query: rownumber helps to fetch IN BETWEEN records (_i.e.,  rownumber BETWEEN 1 and 2 Order by PDATE DESC_)

Comment: @Stennie - MongoDB Version 3.4.3 and Java Driver : mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar

Answer (score 1):

@bharathiraja, hopefully, you've done the migration by now and figured out the steps.  you'll have to convert your inner joins to mongodb lookup operator and then remove nulls (because lookup is left-outer-join-operator).  From your query, looks like you're trying to paginate using row_number().  In Mongodb aggregation framework, after you've done the sort on the PDATE, you can add the limit and skip operator to paginate.

At Couchbase (where I work), we've built row_number() just like standard SQL. Checkout. https://blog.couchbase.com/on-par-with-window-functions-in-n1ql/